# IoC dependency injection - when subject class adds parameter to dependency

Tags: inversion-of-control

I am looking for a patter to resolve my dependency, when the subject class adds a parameter that the dependency requires.

my subject class has:

```
private HTTPServer httpServer;
```

The subject class has UI to ask user for the port number. Once set, the constructor is called:

```
httpServer = new HTTPServer(Port);
httpServer.Start();
httpServer.HttpRequest += httpServer_HttpRequest;
```

Whats the best pattern to address this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I see two possibilities (and personally prefer the first one). This is all written in pseudocode but it should be something like that in most frameworks.

- **Create an empty HTTPServer object and fill it in the process**:

The methods `userEnteredPort` and `userWantsServerStart` are called from button actions:

```
class UI {
    private HTTPServer httpServer;

    @Inject
    public UI(HTTPServer httpServer) {
        this.httpServer = httpServer;
    }

    public void userEnteredPort(int port) {
        httpServer.setPort(port);
    }

    public void userWantsServerStart() {
        if (!httpServer.hasPort()) {
            displayError("No port set");
            return;
        }
        httpServer.start();
    }
}
```

- **Move the port asking GUI part to the httpServer creator**:

Create a Provider class:

```
class HTTPServerCreator extends Provider<HTTPServer> { // or something similar
    public HTTPServer create() {
        MessageDialog md = new MessageDialog("Which port do you want to use?");
        return new HTTPServer(md.getResult);
    }
}
```

Map your provider class to your .class:

```
injector.setProvider(HTTPServer.class, HTTPServerCreator);
```

And use your UI:

```
class UI {
    private HTTPServer httpServer;

    @Inject
    public UI(HTTPServer httpServer) {
        this.httpServer = httpServer;
    }

    public void userWantsServerStart() {
        // server already contains a valid port!
        httpServer.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution - so I figured its a good idea to share back

For the target class (ie HttpServer) I crafted an interface. Then, created a Factory class, with CreateInstance that took the port parameter.

```
    public class HTTPServerFactory
    {
        public virtual IHTTPServer CreateInstance(int port)
        {
            return new HTTPServer(port);
        }
    };
```

Then, for the SUT (subject under test) class, pass it a HTTPServerFactory parameter. The SUT can use its own custom UI/business logic to get the port to use. The SUT then calls CreateInstance on the factory, thus making it possible to mock HTTPServer.